# How to select an Metro listview item with mouse without invoking it?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

This question is about Windows 8 Metro UI's `listview`.

In `listview` with `selectionMode` set to `single`, you can drag an item down (in a `gridLayout`) or to the right(in a `listLayout`) a little bit and release to select the item.

However, how do I select an `listview` item with mouse without invoking it? I tried right click, which triggers a app bar in my application, but in the start screen, a right click on a tile will trigger a selection. How do I make that happen in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question as I just get a response from Microsoft.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/45859830-c12f-4d14-9090-41403e1ddae3

You can use Ctrl+left-click to select an item.

If you are finding the selection behavior differ from the start menu, the reply also says that is a known issue and may be changed in the future release.